# mocha test case for res.render not working

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm writing a simple test case for a route. I've used `mocha`, `chai-http` and `sinon` to check if correct page is rendered or not. This is for `contact` page where the user provides their info. and contact page is rendered again for now. Below is my test case :

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const ejs = require('ejs');


var app = require('../app');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var Contact = require('../models/contacts');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;

describe('Contact', () => {

    describe('/POST Contact', () => {
        it('it should not POST a book without pages field', (done) => {
            var spy = sinon.spy(ejs, '__express');
            let contact = {
                name: "my name",
                msg: "my msg"
            }
            chai.request(app)
                .post('/contact')
                .send(contact)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    console.log(res)
                    //    / console.log(__dirname);


                    // console.log(__filname)
                    // var dir =  __filename + './views/contact.ejs';
                    var dir = path.dirname(fs.realpathSync('./'));;
                    console.log(dir)

                    expect(spy.calledWithMatch(dir + '\views\contact.ejs')).to.be.true;
                    //expect(spy.calledWith(dir)).to.be.true;
                    spy.restore();

                    // Tell Mocha that our test case is done.
                    done();
                    // res.should.have.status(200);
                    //res.should.have.status()
                    // res.should.have.status(200);
                    // res.body.should.be.a('object');
                    //res.body.should.have.property('errors');
                    // res.body.errors.should.have.property('pages');
                    // res.body.errors.pages.should.have.property('kind').eql('required');
                    done();
                });
        });

    });

});
```

The problem is i get an `error response` on `res` saying :

```
     Failed to lookup view &quot;contact&quot; in views directory &quot;C:\\Users\\My User\\Documents\\GitHub\\My Project\\test\\views
```

So basically it searches for `view` inside the `test` directory. Is there any way i can ask to view into the proper directory which is outside test ?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?